# I cannot autologin to pastebin using requests + BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to auto-login to pastebin account using python, but im failing and i don't know why. I copied the request headers exactly and double checked... but still i am greeted with 400 HTTP code. Can somebody help me?

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from requests import Session


# the actual program
page = requests.get("https://pastebin.com/99qQTecB")
parse = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
string = parse.find("textarea")
command = 'hello'
###########################################################
URL = 'https://pastebin.com'
LOGIN_ROUTE ='/login'

d = requests.session()
cfduid = d.get(URL).cookies['__cfduid']

e = requests.session()
csrf = e.get(URL).cookies['_csrf-frontend']

f = requests.session()
pastebin = f.get(URL).cookies['pastebin-frontend']


print (csrf)
print(cfduid)
print(pastebin)

HEADERS = {'Host':'pastebin.com', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br' , 'Referer': 'https://pastebin.com/login', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length': '174', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': "__cfduid=" + cfduid + ";", '_csrf-frontend':csrf + ";"
,'pastebin-frontend':pastebin + ";" ,'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'}

if command in string:
    /super_mario_bros.exe', shell=True)
    s = requests.session()
    csrf_token = s.get(URL).cookies['_csrf-frontend']
    
    login_payload = {
        'LoginForm[username]': 'SECRET',
        'LoginForm[password]': 'Secret', 
        '_csrf-frontend': csrf_token
        }
        #Actual Login
    login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, data=login_payload)
    print(csrf_token)
    print(login_req.status_code)    
    
    
else:
    print("smth")


#print(string)



#Cookie: __cfduid=d955068eb3316226875aa037c059fd8f11595841495; __gads=ID=49ab9fcccba85989:T=1595841504:S=ALNI_MYT-PJZzkGrbYunHFHQE-EEw3vfhQ; _ga=GA1.2.1839432134.1595810341; pastebin-frontend=a9bf2e8c462237148c2d5f6b0832387c; _csrf-frontend=8213fdd4c42f9cfad45ed4993a25a1753c3539b1700c9e92be8ffac00780e34ea%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A14%3A%22_csrf-frontend%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22HHm8aNkQL8XAG8joV8KfCZqOTls50yyW%22%3B%7D; _gid=GA1.2.1476917794.1596212111
```

I am really exhausted cause for the last couple of hours ive been trying to make this work, but still 400 Code is there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're calling `requests.session().get(URL)` multiple times, and it's probably generating new `__cfduid` and `_csrf-frontend` each time

Comment: If i use the same variable it will not work, i have no idea why... can you help me with a solution please?

Comment: Why do you have the string `'LoginForm[username]'` in your payload? Does the HTML form literally have a field with `name="LoginForm[username]"`? Actually yes, nevermind

Comment: yes :))  <input type="text" id="loginform-username" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[username]" value="asasfds" placeholder="Your username" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">

Comment: if I try to use the same session, lets say variable d i get this error: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "paste.py", line 23, in <module>
    csrf = d.get(URL).cookies['_csrf-frontend']
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 328, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 399, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='_csrf-frontend', domain=None, path=None"

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend browser_cookie3:

```
import browser_cookie3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cj = browser_cookie3.load()
s = requests.Session()
for c in cj:
    if 'pastebin' in str(c):
        s.cookies.set_cookie(c)
r = s.get('https://pastebin.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('div.header__user-name').text)
```

prints:

```
UWTD
```

This code take the session cookies from the browser and use them. And prints the username of the user.