# Cannot scrape tag with BeautifulSoup because login with Requests is not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, multiprocessing

In order to scrape the price you have to login. This used to work but now they have changed a few things on their site. The code below still works for the URL, auction, title and results but for the price it only returns nan. If the value in the results list is either 'lot-bid-goes-on' or 'lot-sold' the vehicle should have a value for price.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool 
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell

# Display all output
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
pd.options.display.max_columns = None

# Scrape all vehicles per auction
data_list = [{"searchScope": "SC0520", #value options unique per auction (SC0520 = Indy 2020)
    "searchMake": "Plymouth",
    "searchModel": "Cuda",
    "searchYearStart": "1970",
    "searchYearEnd": "1971",
    "submit": ""},{"searchScope": "SC0520",
    "searchMake": "Dodge",
    "searchModel": "Challenger",
    "searchYearStart": "1970",
    "searchYearEnd": "1971",
    "submit": ""}]

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.mecum.com",
}

login = {"email": "arjenvgeffen@gmail.com",
        "password": "appeltaart13"}

# Get all the newest challenger and cuda lots with the function below
urls = []
title = []
auction = []
results = []
price = []

def newest_vehicles(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post("https://www.mecum.com/includes/login-action.cfm", data=login)
        for data in data_list:
            for item in range(1, 2): #scrapes one page 
                r = req.post(url.format(item), data=data, headers=headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
                target = soup.select("div.lot")
                for tar in target:
                    urls.append(tar.a.get('href'))
                    title.append(tar.select_one("a.lot-title").text)
                    price.append(tar.span.text if tar.span.text else np.NaN)
                    auction.append(tar.select_one("div.lot-number").text.strip())
                    results2 = tar.select("div[class*=lot-image-container]")
                    for result2 in results2:
                        results.append(' '.join(result2['class']))

newest_vehicles("https://www.mecum.com/search/page/{}/")

# There should be 27 unique URLSs
len(urls) #27
len(set(urls)) #27

urls[:2]
title[:2]
results[:2]
auction[:2]
price[:2]
```

Bonus question (you win nothing except your pride and quite possibly the accepted answer:)
If I already have a list with URLS how can I use those as input for a function to scrape the price per URL. The example below scrapes the estimate per URL (final_urls list). I would like a similar function that scrapes the price per URL but that would require some additional code to login first. You can scrape the price like so: price = soup.find("span", class_ = ("lot-price")).text

```
final_urls = ['https://www.mecum.com/lots/SC0520-414334/1970-plymouth-cuda/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/SC0520-414676/1970-plymouth-aar-cuda/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/SC0520-414677/1971-plymouth-cuda-convertible/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/SC0520-414678/1971-plymouth-cuda-convertible/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/SC0520-414733/1971-plymouth-cuda/']

estimate = []
def scrape_estimate(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
            estimate = []
            r = req.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')    
            est = soup.find(class_=["lot-estimate"])
            if est:
                estimate = est.contents[0]
                estimate = re.sub("[\$\,\n\t\' ']", "", estimate)
            else:
                estimate = np.NaN

            return(estimate)

# Example to check just one URL 
scrape_estimate('https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-397356/1971-plymouth-hemi-cuda-sox-and-martin-pro-stock/')

# Scrapes all the URLs in the final_urls list
p = Pool(cpu_count())
results_estimate = p.map(scrape_estimate, final_urls)#sample_urls
p.close()
p.join()

results_estimate
```

I really hope someone can help me fix this, thanks!

Comment: One way to make it maybe is to use browser_cookie3. Se an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63196160/13913639 Note that yo need to login to the site in your browser first.

Comment: @UWTDTV thanks for your suggestion! I have tried it but can't seem to get it to work in combination with my code below, care to show me how you would incorporate browser_cookie3 into my code above? Thanks in advance!